# silverlight toolkit listpicker wp7 missing icons

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, xaml

I'm having a problem with the listpicker (SelectionMode="Multiple"!!!). When i go to fullmode it doesnt show "done", "cancel" icons like if the images were not in my project.

On full screen mode i only have this xaml code

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="listPickerFullModeItemTemplate">
<StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}" FontSize="30" Height="40" FontFamily="Segoe WP"/>
</StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>

<toolkit:ListPicker Header="Floral" SelectionMode="Multiple" FullModeHeader="Floral" CacheMode="BitmapCache" x:Name="floralListPicker" Margin="0,0,12,0" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource listPickerItemTemplate}" FullModeItemTemplate="{StaticResource listPickerFullModeItemTemplate}"/>
```

Code is ok, everything works fine but the icons doesn't show, actually it shows as the default app bar missing icon image. I copied the images from toolkit sample but no go.

anyone know whats wrong?
anyway to force icons on template?

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you need to set the Build Action of the icons to "Content" in their properties window?

Comment: never realized i had to set it as content. That did the trick thank you.

Comment: How to set Build Action of the icons to "Content"?

Answer (score 0):

I found out the solution by exploring the sample solution of the toolkit.

If you don't use a special page for the fullmode selection, you need to include the following images to your project: 
Create one subfolder named `Toolkit.Content` (not ToolKit/Content).

Then, include the files named as this : `ApplicationBar.Cancel.png` and `ApplicationBar.Check.png`. 
Mark them to be generated as content.

That's all! Your icons should now been displayed.

Hope this helps you !